# Hybris Backoffice Advanced Search ReturnRequest Search By Site Info

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, advanced-search

Backoffice I want to search ReturnRequest with site information, but ReturnRequest has no site information on it. There is an order in ReturnRequest and the order has site information.

How can I do it?
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use JOIN's in advanced search. You can use Solr Search for Backoffice. You need to add new indexed types for ReturnRequest to Solr Config for Backoffice.

Comment: Thanks @mkysoft. Your answer does not solve my problem. I want to search by site in ReturnRequest.

Comment: could you give an example source?